# Using filterxpath to get the texts that haven't selectors

Tags: php, xpath

```
<div class="menutitle" onclick="SwitchMenu('sub38');sorter=new table.sorter('sorter');sorter.init('taboastreams38',4);"><meta name="fe38" itemprop="startDate" content="2017-09-19T18:30"><span class="t">19:30</span> <span class="es" style="display: none;">qqqq</span><span class="en">fff</span>  **text here** : <b><span itemprop="name">eee- rrr</span></b></div>
```

I am using php and xpathfilter I tried many times to get the text without selector but I cant . I can get the data from any other selector but this ( **text here**) text in this location i cant .

the code that i used

```
$EventlistNodeValues = $crawler->filterXPath('//div[@class="menutitle"]')->each(function (Crawler $node, $i) {
$event = $node->filterXPath('//'); // i need to change selector here to get text

return json_encode($event,true);
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//div[@class='menutitle']//b/../text()
```

after I used the above xpath pattern I am able to select the first previous of the  tag which is here the text without selectors and this text is what i need to select .